# Delete the row below a specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete a row present below when the cell value in column A has a specific text.

```
Sub DeleteRowWithContentsGuidelines()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim SrchRng
    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
    Do
        Set c = SrchRng.Find("Chart only", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing
End Sub
```

The row above deletes the row which has "Chart only" in the text but I want to delete the row below but not the exact row. is this possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: change to this: `c.Offset(1,0).EntireRow.Delete`

Answer (score 2):

The `.Find` returns a range object, so you can just use something like the following to delete the row below the found text:

```
Sub DeleteRowWithContentsGuidelines()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim SrchRng
    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Activesheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set c = SrchRng.Find("Chart only", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If c is Nothing then Exit Sub
    dim firstAddress : firstAddress = c.Address
    Do
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
        Set c = SrchRng.FindNext(c)
        If c is Nothing then Exit Sub
    Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
End Sub
```

Comment: Good point... there will always be a found range in this case so the code as it is would delete all rows below the first find range - I'll make an adjustment but might need more info from OP to be able to determine exactly what they are trying to do...

Comment: The macro is giving an error at end sub in the IF statement

Comment: That's cos you should only have a single `End Sub` - I've changed to `Exit Sub` instead...  Whoops.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub DeleteRowWithContentsGuidelines()
    Dim c As Range, rDel As Range, i As Long
    Dim SrchRng As Range, s1 As String

    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    s1 = "Chart only"

    With SrchRng
        Set c = .Cells(1)
        For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, s1)
            Set c = .Find(What:=s1, After:=c, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                If rDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rDel = c.Offset(1)
                Else
                    Set rDel = Union(rDel, c.Offset(1))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        rDel.EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The text is not Chart only, it is a part of the text.

Comment: It worked when I change the Chart only to *chart only. Thank you:)

Comment: You don't need to do that. Note the `xlPart` parameter of Find.